Find a Lagrangian subspace complementary to two subspaces
Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space and $A,B$ be two subspaces of $V$ with $2\dim A=2\dim B=\dim V$. I need to prove that there always exists a Lagrangian subspace $L$ of $(V,\omega)$ that is complementary to both $A$ and $B$.
My idea is to consider a Lagrangian subspace $L$ of $(V,\omega)$. If $L\oplus A=V$ and $L\oplus B=V$ then we are done. Now, supposing that $L+A$ does not coincide with $V$, what can I do? Any hint?

This question and generalizations of it have been asked and answered elsewhere on this site. As for your approach, since you need to find $L$ such that $L+A = V$, starting with a $L$ such that $L+A \neq V$ seems inadequate. One thing you could do is prove that there exist arbitrarily small (symplectic) rotations $R$ of $V$ such that $R(A)$ is Lagrangian and $A + R(A) = V$ (i.e. $A \cap R(A) = 0$). There is necessarily one such $R$ (in fact, infinitely many) such that $B + R(A) = V$ too.
